# How to sample the read data from blocking logic safely by using the interface of SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, soc, testbench, uvm

I'm trying to read data from combinational logic.

```
module my_reg(;
  ...
  output reg [31:0] rdata;
)
  ....
  always @(data)
  rdata = 32'h18;
```

and this dut's value is interfaced with a testbench.

```
module test;
...
my_interfcae _if();

my_dut u_my_dut (
...
.HRDATA    (_if.HRDATA),
...
)
```

and the interface is implemented as below:

```
interface my_interface;
...
logic [31:0] HRDATA;
...
endinterface
```

The problem is that I get the `HRDATA` at the first `'x` in the UVM Driver.

In UVM_DRIVER:

```
 ...
 req.HRDATA = ahb_if.HRDATA;
 $display("R3RDATA: %0h", ahb_if.HRDATA);
 ...
```

Especially, the waveform I captured, you can see the `HRDATA` has `'h00000012` ,`'h00000034` and `'h00000056` so on.

[image]

This is the print out from `$display("R3RDATA: %0h", ahb_if.HRDATA);` in Driver.

[image]

How to sample the read data from blocking logic safely in the interface of SystemVerilog without F/F at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simulation race condition.  You are trying to display a signal value at the same time it is changing.  One way to fix it is to add delay before you display.  For example, change:

```
$display("R3RDATA: %0h", ahb_if.HRDATA);
```

to:

```
#1 $display("R3RDATA: %0h", ahb_if.HRDATA);
```

Another way is to change [$display to $strobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832104/display-vs-strobe-vs-monitor-in-verilog).

---

You should always display the simulation time when debugging, something like this:

```
$display($time, " R3RDATA: %0h", ahb_if.HRDATA);
```

Since you are using UVM, you should always use `` `uvm_info `` instead of `$display` since it displays the time by default:

```
#1 `uvm_info ...
```